# xor values of character and space vs xor value of character and character

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, cryptography

How do i prove that xor of character and character is always less than 64 while xor of a space and a character is greater than equal to 64 .

NOTE :that all english characters have ascii in [64, 127] but ascii of space is 32

Comment: look at the most significant bit for character, and the same bit for space

Comment: Can you give an example or a valid proof of this ?Upvoted comment but a proof will make my day .

Comment: Any character with ascii in [64, 127] has a 1 at 7th position in binary (7th position is 64, 6th position is 32). Space has a 0 at the 7th position (because its ascii is 32). So an XOR of a character and space will always have a 1 at the 7th position, meaning that the XOR is >= 64.

Answer (score 0):

Binary representations of several numbers, using seven binary digits:
$$0_{10}=0000000_2\\1_{10}=0000001_2\\2_{10}=0000010_2\\4_{10}=0000100_2\\8_{10}=0001000_2\\16_{10}=0010000_2\\32_{10}=0100000_2\\64_{10}=1000000_2$$
Then, following @AseemBaranwal 's comment, all characters have $1$ in the left most position, while space has $0$. So space XOR character will have $1$ in the left more position, so it is greater (or equal) than $64$. If you have character XOR character, in the left most position you have $1$ XOR $1=0$.